# Biztalk subscriber error

Tags: biztalk

**Can anyone help me with this error message please?**

Event Type: `Error`
Event Source:   `BizTalk Server 2006`
Event Category: `BizTalk Server 2006`
Event ID:   `5778`
Date:       `1/02/2013`
Time:       `7:15:04 AM`
User:       `N/A`
Computer:   `BIZTALKSERVER`
Description:
`The Messaging engine failed to process a message submitted by adapter:SQL Source URL:SQL://SQLSERVER/SQLDB/.`
Details:

```
The published message could not be routed because no subscribers were found.
This error occurs if the subscribing orchestration or send port has not been enlisted,
or if some of the message properties necessary for subscription evaluation have not 
been promoted. Please use the Biztalk Administration console to troubleshoot this failure.
```

Comment: This is a common error reported by BizTalk when an a message arrives which cannot be processed. The schema of the message IS known to BizTalk, however, there is either no Orchestration or Send Port subscribed to the message (also check Context Property filters on subscriptions), or said Orch or Port has become unenlisted. This can also typically happen if an orch expecting further correlated messages dies for some reason, and the expected messages then arrive (but this is NOT a Zombie).

Comment: In other words, what do you expect to happen when that message arrives in the MessageBox? Check that process flow and tie up any loose ends.

Answer (score 0):

What the error is saying is that BizTalk can't determine subscribers for that message. So your starting point would be to check your subscription settings on Send port or orchestration receive shape filter expression.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than checking individual ports, etc. - I'd look at subscriptions via the admin console as a starting point - when viewing the underlying subscriptions the answer as to why no matching subscription is found is sometimes quite obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error message on a system that has been working fine for 36 months. I think it is related to orphaned messages after we restarted the host and send ports. I just went and resumed the message from the Biztalk Group page -> Suspended items/Resumable -> right click resume the message.  all is well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check for the filters in your send ports i.e BTS.ReceivePortName= "Your Receive Port Name".
2. Check the relevant send port is started, Orchestration is enlsited with correct bindings and receive location is enabled
3. After 1st and 2nd steps, go to Plateform setting and restart your Host instances.
4. Refresh your application, Now go to Suspended messages in GroupHub and resume your serviceInstance which should be in resumable state. Now it should be working.

Thanks 
Mayank